# Обратимое шифрование

Tags: шифрование

```
$plain_text = 'aaaaaaaa';
$password = '3c3606d23c3606d2';
```

В `$plain_text` лежит пароль в открытом виде, в `$password` уже зашифрованый. Хочу узнать алгоритм которым был зашифрован пароль, и какой ключ для шифрования там использовался. Была такая мысль что это возможно xor покрытый хексом, однако попытки типа `$password ^ $plain_text` успехом не увенчались. Есть мнение что там используеться блочное шифрование, простой заменой и 4 байтным ключем.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобным и есть мысли какой алгоритм тут используеться ?Или можете дать ссылку статью где есть описание для чайников или пример с описанием :)

Answer (score 3):

Обычно зашифрованный пароль - это результат односторонней хэш-функции (например, md5) от открытого пароля. Расшифровке не подлежит, можно (теоретически) подобрать строку, которая производит тот же хэш.

В Вашем случае действительно похоже на XOR 4-х байтным ключем с представлением результата 16-ричными цифрами. Преобразуйте их (первые 8) в 4-х байтное целое (N) и посмотрите XOR ("aaaa",N) (или поиграйтесь с чем-нибудь аналогичным).

Иногда такой ключ "шифрования" (весьма наивного) получают как сумму (или другую простую функцию) байт шифруемого пароля.

У меня (в тривиальном варианте) получилось, что "aaaaaaaa" 'ксорили' строкой "IgW]" т.е. 5d5767b2 в hex.

**UPD**
 пример программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// в hex() и getx() предполагается, что на входе "ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ" шестнадцатиричные цифры
int
hex (char c)
{
  c = tolower(c);
  if (c < 'a')
    return c-'0';
  return c-'a'+10;
}

int
getx(char *s)
{
  return hex(*s)*16+hex(*(s+1));
}

main ()
{
  char *plain = "aaaa",
    *xpass = "3c3606d2",
    key[5], tst[9];
  key[4] = 0;
  tst[8] = 0;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    key[i] = plain[i]^getx(xpass+(i*2));
  printf ("key = '%s' in hex '",key);
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%02x",key[i] & 0xff);
  printf ("'\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    sprintf(tst+(i*2),"%02x",(plain[i]^key[i])&0xff);
  printf ("plain = '%s' tst password = '%s'\n",plain,tst);

}
```

Вывод:

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc xpass.c 
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
key = ']Wgі' in hex '5d5767b3'
plain = 'aaaa' tst password = '3c3606d2'
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Comment: С вашим ключем у меня вообще что то не получается. А вот c `$secret = ']Wg²';` выходит почти правильно, на экран выводит aaapaaap. Чуствую правда гдето рядом))

Comment: У меня получилось `"]Wg│"`

Comment: А теперь вместо p выводит й, всетаки последний символ не правильный. А как получали ключ ? Интересно, почему у нас разные варианты получаються

Comment: Извините, немного напутал в своем ответе (не учел порядок байт в целых и строках). 

Если говорить именно о строках, то ключ "]Wgі" (шестнадцатиричные 5d5767b3)

Пример (со строками) привожу в **UPD** ответа

Answer (score 2):

Вот мой вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int hex(char c)
{
  if(c>='a' && c<='f') return c-'a'+10;
  else if(c>='A' && c<='F') return c-'A'+10;
  else if(c>='0' && c<='9') return c-'0';
  else return 0;
}

void main()
{
  char plain_text[]="aaaaaaaa";
  char password[]="3c3606d23c3606d2";
  char char_pass[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    char_pass[i]=hex(password[i*2])*16+hex(password[i*2+1]);

  for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    char_pass[i] ^= plain_text[i];

  puts(char_pass);
}
```

Вывод:

```
]Wg│]Wg│
```

Comment: Все очень просто. И у Вас и у меня hex код ключа 5d5767b3. Все символы, кроме 0xb3 это символы ASCII ']Wg'. Очевидно 0xb3 Вы видите в кодировке CP866 (Windows консоль) и там это **символ псевдографики** *вертикальная черта* (не путайте с вертикальной чертой (она же операция ИЛИ) в ASCII (код 0x7c)).

Я в Emacs *eshell* вижу вывод в кодировке CP1251 (Windows файлы) и тут 0xb3 это ***кириллическая i***.

При копи-пасте в ответы видимо тоже какое-то искажение происходит (в моем первом ответе вижу вертикальную черту). В общем, ориентироваться надо на hex код ключа.

Comment: Да, правильно, в хекс-коде получается 5d 57 67 b3

Answer (score 2):

Где то, я встречал такое задание :) 
Тут дело в том, что нужно представлять исходную строку в десятеричном виде, т.е. 979797...
=> отсюда $key = 0x3c3606d23c3606d2 ^ 9797979797979797; Ещё нужно не забывать то, что это блочное шифрование

Comment: Если переводить в десятичную, то
`$key = 0x3c3606d23c3606d2 ^ (97*pow(256,8)+97*pow(256,7)+97*pow(256,6)+...+97)`